# Why does my PS1 environment variable keep getting overwritten?

Tags: ubuntu, zsh, prompt

I'm trying to customize the prompt by adding a line such as

```
export PS1='%d'
```

to my `.zshrc` file. However the environment variable keeps getting overwritten. In fact I can do the following at the terminal

```
% env | grep PS1
PS1=%K{blue}%n@%m%k %B%F{green}%66<...<%~

% export PS1='%d'

% env | grep PS1
PS1=%K{blue}%n@%m%k %B%F{green}%66<...<%~
```

which is just blowing my mind.

What's happening here and how do I stop it?

Comment: why don't just `echo $PS1` instead of `env | grep PS1`?

Comment: Are you using a prompt theme, d'oh-my-zsh or something similar? Also check the functions `precmd` / `preexec` (use `which precmd`, ...), if they modify `$PS1`.

Comment: @phuclv Because I'm still learning this - no other reason.

Comment: @mpy Neither of these commands nor d'oh-my-zsh seem to be installed. I do have byobu though, which came with ubuntu.

Comment: Hm, in such a case I usually start with a clean shell (`zsh -f`) and then source my `~/.zshrc` line by line (or better: block by block) and check when the problem occurs. So this would also by my suggestion in your case.

Comment: When you write "neither of these commands (...) are installed", what do you mean. `precmd` and `preexec` are shell built-ins. Do you mean `which precmd` returns nothing?

Comment: @mpy I meant that `which` doesn't return anything for either command. Also calling them yields `command not found` in both cases.